# Can't drag div if have total height of containment

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, draggable, containment

I have a div with the follow css:

```
.azul{
   height:100%;
   width:100px;
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   background-color:blue;
}
```

The 100% height is the same height of the container.

I bind the "dragstart" to a function. that function resize the div to a smaller height.

If i define:

```
jQuery(element).draggable({ containment: ".container" });
```

The div is resized well, but cant move it Y position, only X, so...the left css attribute change, but the top no...

I deduce that when the drag start, jquery-ui take the initial height of the div ( the 100%), and when i change it in the function...the jquery-ui dont allow me to move Y position becuase the 100% is stored somewhere...

I tried to dont put 100% and make dinamical with px value...

Thanks is advice !!!

Comment: Maybe your problem doesn't depend on your js but a working jsfiddle would help to understand and see your problem.. with a jsfiddle its much more easy to help you

Comment: I find jsfiddle is a kind of online debugging between people? My code have comercial porpouses sorry, cant show it.

Comment: You don't have to post your complete code.. just your problem in a nutshell to help others test and work on your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to resize before dragStart.

```
jQuery(".panel").bind("mousedown", onDragStart);
```